# Are there any free/open source databases which can properly store arrays?

Tags: sql, database

I am looking for a free/open source database which can properly store (multi-dimensional) arrays.

Once the array is stored in the database, the items in that array should be searchable within the database. This means, I don't want to serialize it.

It should be able to run under Linux (SuSe), and I want to use it with Python and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL, you can do

```
CREATE TABLE MyArray (
    RowIndex INTEGER,
    ColIndex INTEGER,
    Value    /* whatever type the array elements have */,
    UNIQUE (RowIndex, ColIndex)
);
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean that when 10.000 people fill in my survey I get 10.000 db tables?

Comment: Nope, you just add a SurveyID column to the table and to the UNIQUE constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). It's a fast and feature-rich document database, capable of storing and searching arrays and objects ("documents"). It has client libraries for a lot of different languages, including PHP and Python.

There are some alternatives as well, for example [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/), but I haven't tested them myself.

Edit: I see now that you've tagged the question "sql". Neither of these databases is relational and does not implement SQL. They are, however, competent and worth checking out.

Comment: Can/should MongoDB totally replace mySQL/postgreSQL?

Comment: That decision is entirely up to you. NoSQL databases are a different paradigm and as such does the job in a different manner. What you "should" and "should not" do depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Firebird has array support, but I don't know that you can retrieve specific array elements via Query.  I think you have to retrieve the array as a field, then parse it using your other scripting language.  I know Kinterbasdb for Python supports storing / retrieving them.  We considered this briefly, but for our needs serialization of the data actually ended up making more sense.

Comment: Serialization is in my case not an option. I work with dynamic forms. The amount and type of questions are based on it's topic (a survey). Therefor I need to store the given answers given by our visitors as an array into a db, which are searchable.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has built-in [array data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/arrays.html). You can declare a column to store an array and your SELECT queries can access individual array elements.